# How to calculate date time values over python list items

Tags: python, list, math

I have a python list that stores data for emails received and emails sent within same email thread. Emails received are marked as `Email-In`, and emails sent as `Email-Out`. Each `Email-In` or `Email-Out` has assigned specific `requestID` for the email thread and time stamp.

For example, for email thread with `requestId` = 735482556 there is incoming email on 15-May-2020 at 11:15:52:

```
[735482556, 'Email-In', '15-May-2020 11:15:52']
```

Values on my `correspondence_list` will change everyday and show data for different requestIDs as this script will scan my data daily.

My current `correspondence_list`:

```
[[735482556, 'Email-In', '15-May-2020 11:15:52'], [735482556, 'Email-Out', '15-May-2020 22:42:50'], [735482556, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 11:58:41'], [735532797, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 07:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 10:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-Out', '17-May-2020 11:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-In', '17-May-2020 13:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-Out', '17-May-2020 15:44:15'], [567432221, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 20:30:15'], [567432221, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 20:35:15'], [567432221, 'Email-Out', '16-May-2020 20:45:15']]
```

What I'm trying to do with the above list is to calculate differences in time for Email-In and Email-Out in order to see how much it takes to reply to incoming emails. Each requestId can have multiple emails in/out depending on how many replies request has gotten.

So for example, `requestId`= 735482556 has 3 items. In this case I need to calculate the time difference between `Email-In` and `Email-Out` which is '11:26:58' and ignore the second `'Email-In'` sent on `'16-May-2020 11:58:41'` as there is no Email-Out to pair it with.

```
 [735482556, 'Email-In', '15-May-2020 11:15:52'], [735482556, 'Email-Out', '15-May-2020 22:42:50'], [735482556, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 11:58:41']
```

Desired output for my current `correspondence_list`:

```
 [[735482556, '11:26:58'], [735532797, 'not replied'], [66789544, '15:00:00', '02:15:00'],  [567432221, '0:15:00']
```

my code so far:

```
from datetime import datetime

s1 = '15-May-2020 11:15:52'
s2 = '15-May-2020 22:42:50' 
FMT = '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)

def format_timedelta(tdelta):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(tdelta.seconds + tdelta.days * 86400, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return '{:d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)


myDifference = format_timedelta(tdelta)
```

the above code allows me to calculate time difference manually for each instance. However, I'm trying to understand how I could iterate it over my list and calculate within list ignoring calculation if there is no pair for Email-in and Email-Out in thread. Could someone help with this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `correspondence_list` to dictionary then you can find the difference iterating through each `request_id`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

correspondence_list = [[735482556, 'Email-In', '15-May-2020 11:15:52'], [735482556, 'Email-Out', '15-May-2020 22:42:50'], [735482556, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 11:58:41'], [735532797, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 07:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 10:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-Out', '17-May-2020 11:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-In', '17-May-2020 13:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-Out', '17-May-2020 15:44:15'], [567432221, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 20:30:15'], [567432221, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 20:35:15'], [567432221, 'Email-Out', '16-May-2020 20:45:15']]

email_dict = defaultdict(list)
for email in correspondence_list:
    email_dict[email[0]].append(email[1:])

#sorting the lists based on time
for x in email_dict:
    email_dict[x] = sorted(email_dict[x], key = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1], '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'))

def days_between(d1, d2):
    tdelta = abs(datetime.strptime(d1, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(d2, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
    minutes, seconds = divmod(tdelta.seconds + tdelta.days * 86400, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60) 
    return '{:d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)

correspondence_list = []
for request_id in email_dict:
    if len(email_dict[request_id]) == 1:
        correspondence_list.append([request_id, 'not replied'])
    else:
        idx, lst = 0, []
        while idx < len(email_dict[request_id]):
            z = email_dict[request_id][idx: idx + 2]
            if len(z) == 2 and sorted(z[0][0] + z[1][0]) == sorted('Email-In' + 'Email-Out'):
                lst.append(days_between(z[0][1], z[1][1]))
                idx += 2
            else:
                idx += 1
        correspondence_list.append([request_id] + lst)
print(correspondence_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[[735482556, '11:26:58'],
 [735532797, 'not replied'],
 [66789544, '25:00:00', '2:00:00'],
 [567432221, '0:10:00']]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is find all matches. I will assume that `requestID` is unique and that there are no duplicate outgoing e-mails. In other words, there is only one pair of outgoing ingoing emails per ID.

In that case you have several options.

For example, you can loop over the list twice and check the id and ingoing outgoing messages.

```
for ID, email, time in correspondence_list:
    if email.endswith("In"):
        for ID_2, email_2, time_2 in correspondence_list:
            if email_2.endswith("Out") and ID == ID_2:
                #  calculate time
```

Or you try and match them going from the start.

```
sorted_correspondence = dict()
for ID, email, time in correspondence_list:
    sorted_correspondence.get(ID, []).append(time)
```

Now you can loop over the dictionary and the values should be your two time stamps. In case there is only 1 value, you can conclude that there is no answer yet and skip them, by not processing.

### Edit

Just noticed you wanted to check for multiple ingoing and outgoing e-mails. In that case you can use the dictionary approach and also add the email data to it. In that case you have to check which are in and outgoing. In case there is always one outgoing and one incoming you can alternate the values to match them. In case there are multiple in coming email or multiple outcoming emails you can maybe try to create a stack for all outgoing e-mails and pop them per incoming e-mail. But the last action really depends on how the replies should be matched to the incoming e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

In order to ease the process of calculating the difference in time between ingoing and outgoing emails, you should prepare a data structure.

Fitting well, in my opinion, is a dictionary holding all emails under their `RequestID`.

```
correspondence_list = [
    [735482556, 'Email-In', '15-May-2020 11:15:52'], 
    [735482556, 'Email-Out', '15-May-2020 22:42:50'], 
    [735482556, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 11:58:41'], 
    [735532797, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 07:44:15'], 
    [66789544, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 10:44:15'], 
    [66789544, 'Email-Out', '17-May-2020 11:44:15'], 
    [66789544, 'Email-In', '17-May-2020 13:44:15'], 
    [66789544, 'Email-Out', '17-May-2020 15:44:15'], 
    [567432221, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 20:30:15'], 
    [567432221, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 20:35:15'], 
    [567432221, 'Email-Out', '16-May-2020 20:45:15']
]

# Calculatiing unique `RequestIDs`
request_ids = set([i[0] for i in correspondence_list])
# {66789544, 567432221, 735482556, 735532797}

mail_dict = {request_id: [(ce[1], ce[2]) for ce in c if ce[0]==request_id] for request_id in request_ids}
```

### Output:

```
{   66789544: [   ('Email-In', '16-May-2020 10:44:15'),
                  ('Email-Out', '17-May-2020 11:44:15'),
                  ('Email-In', '17-May-2020 13:44:15'),
                  ('Email-Out', '17-May-2020 15:44:15')],
    567432221: [   ('Email-In', '16-May-2020 20:30:15'),
                   ('Email-In', '16-May-2020 20:35:15'),
                   ('Email-Out', '16-May-2020 20:45:15')],
    735482556: [   ('Email-In', '15-May-2020 11:15:52'),
                   ('Email-Out', '15-May-2020 22:42:50'),
                   ('Email-In', '16-May-2020 11:58:41')],
    735532797: [('Email-In', '16-May-2020 07:44:15')]}
```

Having that, it should not be a big deal to process the emails and find differences in time in between them or if they are not answered at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an ID, I would recommend that you create a python dictionary where the key is the id, and each value is a list of in and out e-mail timestamps. For example,

```
import datetime

import numpy as np


def calculate_dt_from_two_strings(latter, earlier):
    r"""Converts a timestamp to a datetime.
    """
    FMT = '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(latter, FMT) - datetime.datetime.strptime(earlier, FMT)


IDX_ID = 0
IDX_E_MAIL = 1
IDX_TIMESTAMP = 2

correspondence_list = [
    [735482556, 'Email-In', '15-May-2020 11:15:52'], [735482556, 'Email-Out', '15-May-2020 22:42:50'], [735482556, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 11:58:41'], [735532797, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 07:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 10:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-Out', '17-May-2020 11:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-In', '17-May-2020 13:44:15'], [66789544, 'Email-Out', '17-May-2020 15:44:15'], [567432221, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 20:30:15'], [567432221, 'Email-In', '16-May-2020 20:35:15'], [567432221, 'Email-Out', '16-May-2020 20:45:15']]


correspondence_ids = np.unique(
    [correspondence[IDX_ID] for correspondence in correspondence_list])


correspondence_dict = {id: [] for id in correspondence_ids}


for correspondence in correspondence_list:
    correspondence_dict[correspondence[IDX_ID]].append(correspondence)


for correspondence_id, correspondence_history in correspondence_dict.items():
    correspondence_pairs = np.array_split(correspondence_history, 2)

    for corresponce_pair in correspondence_pairs:
        if len(corresponce_pair) == 2:
            # We have an E-Mail Out for an E-Mail in.
            earliery_timestamp = corresponce_pair[0][IDX_TIMESTAMP]
            latter_timestamp = corresponce_pair[1][IDX_TIMESTAMP]

            print(earliery_timestamp, latter_timestamp)

            dt_corresponce_pair = calculate_dt_from_two_strings(latter_timestamp, earliery_timestamp)

            print(dt_corresponce_pair)
```

I don't know your specificities, but this should do the job. As you can see, I assumed that you can use numpy in the project.

I hope this helps!